# Is my current employee allowed to work privately with ex customer?

Tags: professionalism, privacy

I have a disability support business. One employee was working with a client of ours. This client no longer wanted services from the business, but wanted to hire my employee privately to continue working with her as a contractor. This now impacts the work shifts I can offer this employee. Is this poaching? How do I address this?

Comment: How you _should_ have addressed this was by having a no-poach clause in your contracts, both with your employees and your clients. I'm assuming at this point you didn't do that, at which point the question I'd be asking is whether it's worth fighting this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-compete_clause

Comment: What do you mean it affects shifts? Did you employee tell you they cannot work hours they worked before? Would that not be a problem, even if she sat on the beach having icecream instead of servicing your ex client? What would you do in that case?

Comment: Does the law prohibit them from working with this customer? Do you have a legally binding contract that prohibits them from working with this customer? Do you own this employee? If the answer to these question is no, then there probably isn't anything you can do. People are free to work where and for whom they want.

Comment: Are you willing to fire the employee if he/she don't want to do as you say?

Answer (score 11):

> Is my current employee allowed to work privately with ex customer?

They are allowed, unless your employment contract (or local labor allows) specifically disallow that.

Many employment contracts have clauses that regulate what other work (or not) your employees can do besides your employment and what relationships to your customers are allowed. These are often called "non-compete" and the details what can or not be put in such agreement or its enforceability vary a lot with location (even inside a single country like the US).

Since you are asking here I assume that your current contract has no such clause. If you want something like this for future employees, I suggest discussing with a local labor lawyer.

For the current situation, you have the following choices

1. Just accept it
2. Tell your employee to stop. They may or may not comply. What consequences this may have and what you can do about it, depends a lot on your location.
3. Update the employment contract retroactively to explicitly prohibit this. However you can't force the employee to sign it, so  you are back to point #2

Answer (score 2):

while you may not like them doing this, unless there is something in the contract between company and employer, and the contract between company and customer, your options will be limited. In addition any applicable contract clause will also have to follow the employment law in your area.

Assuming that you can't stop it, there is one action that you need to take: Remind the employee and the customer that this new relationship is not covered on the previous contract.

In the US that would mean that this work is not W-2 work it is 1099. In the US that would  mean that the client and the contractor may have to address this on their taxes.  The actual rules will vary by country,

The contractor is no longer protected by the company liability coverage while working with this client. In addition if the contractor has to miss a shift, the client will have to be happy with no support that day.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you should have had a clause in your contract with the employee and the client.

- If the employee misses a shift or takes extra time off then I think you may have justification in terminating their employment.
- If the knowledge available at your work helps this person work for the other party, then you may have a case to protect your IP.
- If that client comes back again, I would refuse to do work for them.
- Don't give the employee any pay rises or additional benefits.
- Change both your contracts now before you lose more employees.  Consider putting in a non-competition clause in the employment contract.